# MultiInputFilter not working for 3 inputs in AndroidFastImageProcessing

Tags: android, image-processing, shader, opengl-es-2.0, gpuimage

I am using [this library for GPUImage processing](https://github.com/chrisbatt/AndroidFastImageProcessing).

I am trying to run filters in parallel like we do in [iOS GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) library, but I am having issues while adding 3 inputs to one filter which extends `MultiInputFilter`.
I am trying to combine

1. `BasicCameraInputFilter`
2. `CannyEdgeDetectionFilter`
3. `SobelEdgeDetectionFilter`

where `BasicCameraInputFilter` is direct camera input.

```
BasicCameraInputFilter cameraInput = new BasicCameraInputFilter();
CannyEdgeDetectionFilter cannyEdgeDetectionFilter = new CannyEdgeDetectionFilter(1.0f,0.3f,0.6f);
SobelEdgeDetectionFilter sobelEdgeDetectionFilter = new SobelEdgeDetectionFilter();
CombinationFilter combinationFilter = new CombinationFilter();

cameraInput.addTarget(combinationFilter);
cannyEdgeDetectionFilter.addTarget(combinationFilter);
sobelEdgeDetectionFilter.addTarget(combinationFilter);
combinationFilter.registerFilterLocation(cameraInput,0);
combinationFilter.registerFilterLocation(cannyEdgeDetectionFilter,1);
combinationFilter.registerFilterLocation(sobelEdgeDetectionFilter,2);
combinationFilter.addTarget(this);

registerInitialFilter(cameraInput);
registerFilter(cannyEdgeDetectionFilter);
registerFilter(sobelEdgeDetectionFilter);
registerTerminalFilter(combinationFilter);
```

Here is my fragment shader for my `CombinationFilter`

```
 "precision mediump float;\n"
+"uniform sampler2D " + UNIFORM_TEXTURE0 + ";\n"
+"uniform sampler2D " + UNIFORM_TEXTUREBASE + 1 + ";\n"
+"uniform sampler2D " + UNIFORM_TEXTUREBASE + 2 + ";\n"
+"varying vec2 " + VARYING_TEXCOORD + ";\n"

+"void main(){\n"
+"   vec4 color1 = texture2D(" + UNIFORM_TEXTURE0 + ", " + VARYING_TEXCOORD + ");\n"
+"   vec4 color2 = texture2D(" + UNIFORM_TEXTUREBASE + 1 + ", " + VARYING_TEXCOORD + ");\n"
+"   vec4 color3 = texture2D(" + UNIFORM_TEXTUREBASE + 2 + ", " + VARYING_TEXCOORD + ");\n"

+"   vec4 whiteColor = vec4(1.0);\n"
+"   whiteColor.r = color1.r * color2.r * color3.r;\n"
+"   whiteColor.g = color1.g * color2.g * color3.g;\n"
+"   whiteColor.b = color1.b * color2.b * color3.b;\n"
+"   gl_FragColor =  whiteColor;\n"
+"}\n";
```

Comment: What are the issues you are having?

Comment: there are no errors, it just doesn't work, and we cant debug shaders right..

Answer (score 4):

The [library](https://github.com/chrisbatt/AndroidFastImageProcessing) you're using is out dated and I don't think its being maintained as its author has not been active since 2015. If you're trying to manipulate images on android, then I'll using [opencv](https://opencv.org/platforms/android/). Here is how you'd combine the Canny and Sobel filters.

```
public class ImageManipulationsActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {
    private static final String  TAG                 = "OCVSample::Activity";

    private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;

    private Mat                  mIntermediateMat;

    public static int           viewMode = VIEW_MODE_RGBA;

    private BaseLoaderCallback  mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                } break;
                default:
                {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                } break;
            }
        }
    };

    public ImageManipulationsActivity() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);


        mOpenCvCameraView = new CameraBridgeViewBase(this);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);

        setContentView(mOpenCvCameraView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
            mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onCreateOptionsMenu");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onOptionsItemSelected; selected item: " + item);

        return false;
    }

    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        mIntermediateMat = new Mat();
    }

    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
        // Explicitly deallocate Mats
        if (mIntermediateMat != null)
            mIntermediateMat.release();

        mIntermediateMat = null;
    }

    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        Mat rgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        Size sizeRgba = rgba.size();

        Mat rgbaInnerWindow;


            rgbaInnerWindow = rgba.submat(top, top + height, left, left + width);
            Imgproc.Canny(rgbaInnerWindow, mIntermediateMat, 80, 90);

            Mat grayInnerWindow = gray.submat(top, top + height, left, left + width);
            Imgproc.Sobel(mIntermediateMat, grayInnerWindow, CvType.CV_8U, 1, 1);
            Core.convertScaleAbs(grayInnerWindow, mIntermediateMat, 10, 0);
            Imgproc.cvtColor(mIntermediateMat, rgbaInnerWindow, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA, 4);
            grayInnerWindow.release();
            rgbaInnerWindow.release();


        return rgba;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the brief answer Niza, but does opencv works on GPU?